# presenting results in a group asp.net mvc razor linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am trying to display data in a certain manner. Let's say I have a database with a number of restaurants, where some are individually owned others are chains. The way I want to represent my results is that all restaurants are only listed once. If it is a chain I want it to say "Burger King" 25 more found. I want to prevent that users have to browse through page and pages of the same restaurant.

The restaurant table does contain a ChainId column.

I have no idea how I should approach this.
Do I work this out at the data level with a group by? how do I implement something at the presentation level. I know that this is a very poor formulated question but I am not quite sure ow to put it better. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I work this out at the data level with a group by?

That sounds like a good approach.

> how do I implement something at the presentation level

I would instead start with the *model*.  If you model your data such that one "chain" can have one or more "locations" then the UI should be pretty straightforward.